# python crontab SyntaxError: '(' was never closed

Tags: python, python-3.x

Am try to explore python batch via crontab am writing below two program and try to start python
Note : am try to start via system_cron
while running i got error from crontab.py , crontab.py is creating during pip install pyton-crontab hence its a lib file am not sure what am missing here

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\myusername\python_details\batch_two\time_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from crontab import CronTab
  File "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\crontab.py", line 3
    cron.remove_all(time="'* * * * *')"
                   ^
SyntaxError: '(' was never closed
```

```
below is my  python batch code ->

from crontab import CronTab
system_cron   = CronTab(tabfile='C:/Users/myusername/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python311/site-packages/crontab.py', user=False)   -> i tried both False & True 
job = system_cron.new(command='python my_time.py') # here i added actual location 
system_cron.write()
```

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to pass `.../site-packages/crontab.py` as *the `tabfile` argument*. You're probably supposed to pass the path to a *crontab* file; a file defining cron jobs.

Comment: in windows how to create crontab file

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your installation of the `crontab` package is corrupt with a syntax error.

If you've actually done

```
CronTab(tabfile='C:/Users/myusername/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python311/site-packages/crontab.py', user=False)
```

and then called `.write()`, no big surprise – you've had the `crontab` package parse its own source [as a crontab file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Overview), edit it, and write it back, causing Python syntax errors.

You'll need to reinstall the `crontab` package, and then point your code at an actual crontab file, not the source code of the package itself.

(By the way, on Windows there's nothing that would read or run crontabs by default.)

Comment: i tried task schedule in windows its working fine, i want to explore and run  crontab with cron expression using windows.